# how to include a specific helper file in a spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm not really sure why this isn't working. I have a test for omniauth and there is a set_omniauth method that gets called in the below spec (automagically). This test fails if called via

rspec spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb

but passes when the whole suite is run via like `rspec spec`. How would I include the `spec/helpers/omniauth_helpers.rb` file? I have tried:

```
require 'omniauth_helpers'
require 'spec/helpers/omniauth_helpers'
require 'omniauth_helpers.rb'
require 'spec/helpers/omniauth_helpers.rb'
```

but they don't work.

Here is my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController, "OmniAuth", task049: true do
  before do
    request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] # is set in
  end

  it "task049: sets a session variable to the OmniAuth auth hash - see the set_omniauth() in spec/helpers/omniauth_helpers" do
    request.env["omniauth.auth"]['uid'].should == '1234fb'
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this a Rails application? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, this did it:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'helpers/omniauth_helpers'


describe SessionsController, "OmniAuth", task049: true do
```

Was a late night last night.